# Is there an Excel array formula to return 1 for the first occurrence of a value, and 0 for subsequent occurrences

Tags: arrays, excel

I need an Excel formula to return 1 for every unique text values for a sequence and 0 for duplicate in the same sequence.

I included this screenshot. <--- **correction**

[Desired Output--> 1 for every unique text value and 0 for its duplicate but for a the next number in ID the counting restart from zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqqXm.png)

Thanks
Gianluca

Comment: `=--(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,B2)=1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @BigBen but the solution is not quite right because my screenshot was incomplete. My bad.I uploaded the correct one

Comment: `=--(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)=1)`